# Android view Binding - how to do conditional inflation

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

i am trying to control the binding file based on a boolean, but android wont compile and says ids not found. here is what i have so far:

```
private val binding =
        if (config.isExperimentOn()) {
            ExperimentBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, false)
        } else {
            OriginalBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, false)

        }
```

i tried putting this in a lazy block , does not help. if i comment out the if condition everything works as long as i pick just one binding. how to do conditional binding here?  Keep in mind the files will have the same Ids as there almost duplicate.

Comment: File having same ids won't help in this case because These classes r on same level as child of `ViewBinding` they r not related at all. You need to check `instanceOf` or `is` in this case to further access the views from binding object.

Comment: before view binding it was so easy to  just have two xml layouts and have a if condition on which one to load. what about DataBindingUtil class. let me look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally was able to figure this out ....

your view bindings file has a bind method which means it can bind to any layout you want. so first i inflate the respective layout i want and then i bind to it later:

```
val layout = if (predicate) {
        inflate(R.layout.layout_one)
    } else {
        inflate(layout_two)
    }


private val binding =
        MyBinding.bind(layout) 
//force your binding to take the respectivelayout
```